# Visual Studio 2013 - Change in code doesn't show when debugging

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I am working on a project and sometimes when I change the code and then debug to see my changes it doesn't show them.

Is there a bug in Visual Studio 2013 or are there any settings?

Comment: Does it help if you clean the sollution?

Comment: No. I cleaned and rebuilt multiple times, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: post and example with code before and after debug

Comment: For example I have a code in CSS which splits a picture in 3 equal parts. If I change the picture with another picture, when I press F5 to run the code, it still shows me the previous picture.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. It was a cache setting in Chrome. All I had to do was to enter Settings -> Clear browsing data... -> remove the thick from the "Browsing history". :)